# How can I detect when a print operation is finished?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

I'm currently using NSView print: method. I'm customizing my view for printing, but I would like to restore previous settings when the print is finished.

How can I know when a print operation is committed or canceled ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create your [`NSPrintOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintOperation_Class/), use  [`-runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000362) to run it with a specified delegate (to restore the previous settings) to be called when the print operation is completed.

The "[Printing Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Tasks/CreatingPrintJob.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000861-BAJBFGED)" guide has an example of how to do this.